Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details
I'm having issue with firebase_core, after downgrade the flutter version or upgrading the flutter version**(3.24.3, stable)**.
Flutter 3.22.3 • channel stable • revision b0850beeb2 (9 weeks ago) • 2024-07-16 21:43:41 -0700
Engine • revision 235db911ba
Tools • Dart 3.4.4 • DevTools 2.34.3
and there is firebase plugins version -
firebase_core: ^3.4.1
firebase_auth: ^4.1.0
firebase_core
cloud_firestore: ^4.5.0
firebase_core
firebase_storage: ^11.0.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.0.0
Should i change the Android sdk version or what.
while running on android or build an apk then i'm getting that issue.
Please help me and thank you in advance.


Error /Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:12: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BasicMessageChannel;
^
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:13: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger;
^
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:14: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MessageCodec;
^
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:15: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec;
^
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:516: error: cannot find symbol
private static class FirebaseCoreHostApiCodec extends StandardMessageCodec {
^
symbol: class StandardMessageCodec
location: class GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:560: error: cannot find symbol
static @nonnull MessageCodec getCodec() {
^
symbol: class MessageCodec
location: interface FirebaseCoreHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:567: error: cannot find symbol
static void setup(@nonnull BinaryMessenger binaryMessenger, @nullable FirebaseCoreHostApi api) {
^
symbol: class BinaryMessenger
location: interface FirebaseCoreHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:672: error: cannot find symbol
static @nonnull MessageCodec getCodec() {
^
symbol: class MessageCodec
location: interface FirebaseAppHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:678: error: cannot find symbol
static void setup(@nonnull BinaryMessenger binaryMessenger, @nullable FirebaseAppHostApi api) {
^
symbol: class BinaryMessenger
location: interface FirebaseAppHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:16: error: package io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins does not exist
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin;
^
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
implements FlutterPlugin,
^
symbol: class FlutterPlugin
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
public void onAttachedToEngine(FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
^
symbol: class FlutterPluginBinding
location: class FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
public void onDetachedFromEngine(@nonnull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
^
symbol: class FlutterPluginBinding
location: class FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:521: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@OverRide
^
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:525: error: cannot find symbol
return PigeonFirebaseOptions.fromList((ArrayList) readValue(buffer));
^
symbol: method readValue(ByteBuffer)
location: class FirebaseCoreHostApiCodec
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:527: error: cannot find symbol
return PigeonInitializeResponse.fromList((ArrayList) readValue(buffer));
^
symbol: method readValue(ByteBuffer)
location: class FirebaseCoreHostApiCodec
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:529: error: non-static variable super cannot be referenced from a static context
return super.readValueOfType(type, buffer);
^
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:529: error: cannot find symbol
return super.readValueOfType(type, buffer);
^
symbol: method readValueOfType(byte,ByteBuffer)
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:533: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@OverRide
^
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:542: error: non-static variable super cannot be referenced from a static context
super.writeValue(stream, value);
^
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:542: error: cannot find symbol
super.writeValue(stream, value);
^
symbol: method writeValue(ByteArrayOutputStream,Object)
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:569: error: cannot find symbol
BasicMessageChannel channel =
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseCoreHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:570: error: cannot find symbol
new BasicMessageChannel<>(
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseCoreHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:601: error: cannot find symbol
BasicMessageChannel channel =
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseCoreHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:602: error: cannot find symbol
new BasicMessageChannel<>(
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseCoreHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:630: error: cannot find symbol
BasicMessageChannel channel =
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseCoreHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:631: error: cannot find symbol
new BasicMessageChannel<>(
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseCoreHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:673: error: cannot find symbol
return new StandardMessageCodec();
^
symbol: class StandardMessageCodec
location: interface FirebaseAppHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:680: error: cannot find symbol
BasicMessageChannel channel =
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseAppHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:681: error: cannot find symbol
new BasicMessageChannel<>(
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseAppHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:712: error: cannot find symbol
BasicMessageChannel channel =
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseAppHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:713: error: cannot find symbol
new BasicMessageChannel<>(
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseAppHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:744: error: cannot find symbol
BasicMessageChannel channel =
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseAppHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore.java:745: error: cannot find symbol
new BasicMessageChannel<>(
^
symbol: class BasicMessageChannel
location: interface FirebaseAppHostApi
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:36: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@OverRide
^
/Users/sangeetasingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.5.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:43: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@OverRide
^
36 errors
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

